# Laravel: collection map() returns wrong data

Tags: php, laravel

I have adverts (eloquent collection) with eager loaded advert attributes (details) and their values:

```
$adverts = Advert::where('category_id', 1312)->with(['attributesValues.attribute'])->get();

$adverts->map(function (Advert $advert) {
    $details = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();

    foreach ($advert->attributesValues as $attributeValue) {
        $detail = $attributeValue->attribute;
        $detail->value = $attributeValue->value;

        $details->push($detail);
    }

    $advert->details = $details;

    echo ('<br>' . $advert->title . '<br>');
    foreach ($advert->details as $detail) {
        echo ('- ' . $detail->name . ': ' . $detail->value . '<br>');
    }

    return $advert;
});

echo ('<br><hr>');
foreach ($adverts as $advert) {
    echo ('<br>' . $advert->title . '<br>');
    foreach ($advert->details as $detail) {
        echo ('- ' . $detail->name . ': ' . $detail->value . '<br>');
    }
}
die;
```

My Models are:

```
class Advert extends Model
{
  // @property int $id
  // @property string $title
  // @property int $category_id

  public function attributesValues()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(AttributeValue::class, 'advert_id', 'id');
  }
}


class Attribute extends Model
{
  // @property int $id
  // @property string $name
}


class AttributeValue extends Model
{
  // @property int $advert_id
  // @property int $attribute_id
  // @property string $value

  public function attribute()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class, 'attribute_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

**Issue**

If I try to dump advert and its details just before return inside the map(), I get correct data:

```
Product 1
- Model: Eva
- Size: L
- Color: blue

Product 2
- Model: Maya
- Size: S
- Color: green

Product 3
- Model: Royal
- Size: M
- Color: black
```

But if I dump after mapping, "details" attribute of all adverts become the same (details of the last advert), which is wrong:

```
Product 1
- Model: Royal
- Size: M
- Color: black

Product 2
- Model: Royal
- Size: M
- Color: black

Product 3
- Model: Royal
- Size: M
- Color: black
```

**Questions**

1. Why it is going on?
2. How to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead second foreach, `dd($adverts->pluck('id')->toArray());` to double check and confirm `$adverts` collection contains same `Advert` objects.

Comment: @Tpojka - `$adverts` collection contains different `Adverts` as it should be, the same are their details

Comment: What do you think your map function should be doing? Why are there a bunch of `echo` statements in it? Why do you not just loop over the `attributeValues` collection in your view? Where are you defining a `name` property? And yes, as already answered, you are not using the return value of `map()`.

Comment: @miken32 1) My `map` function should return collection of `Adverts`, where each `Advert` has extra attribute `details` (collection of `Attributes` with each `Attribute` value).
2) `echo` statements are used to show the result which the code return.
3) I do not loop over the `attributeValues` collection in view, because I think it would be more convenient to have one collection containing all data in the view.
4) `name` is the property of `Attribute` model. Why do I need to define it?
5) `You are not using the return value of map().` - Why? How should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to [replicate your issue](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/d788be2d-fb55-439a-9128-2c42f068059b) but haven't figured out *why* it happens. The answer is almost certain to involve references.

While the `$details` object is different for each element of `$adverts`, the elements of the `$details` collection are the same for all 3. Not just the same values, but the same object (you can confirm this by using `dump()` and looking at object IDs.)

The easy answer here is to use a sensible loop in your view, rather than mangling models with a bunch of dynamic properties.

```php
$adverts = Advert::where('category_id', 1312)->with(['attributesValues.attribute'])->get();
```

```php
@foreach ($adverts as $advert)
<p style="color:green">
  {{ $advert->title }}<br/>
  @foreach ($advert->attributeValues as $val)
    - {{ $val->attribute->name }}: {{ $val->value }}<br/>
  @endforeach
</p>
@endforeach
```

If you insist on making things uneccessarily complicated, assign the return from `map()` as Marcin says in the other answer, and also convert `$detail` to an array and back again before pushing it onto the collection.

```php
$detail = (object)$detail->toArray();
```

See [this live example](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/d69800d9-5f30-4034-97f9-81d62b604b2b) for a demo of both solutions working.

Comment: YES, it works: `… converting $detail to an array and back again before pushing it onto the collection`. Thank You so much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are getting those results and if you pasted the whole code, but for `map` instead of:

```
$adverts->map(function (Advert $advert) {
```

you should use:

```
$adverts = $adverts->map(function (Advert $advert) {
```

to assign result of map to variable

Comment: Unfortunately, result is the same

Comment: @Dmitrijs Is the code you pasted exact code you are using? Or maybe you pasted simplified scenario but you haven't showed something else that could explain the problem

Comment: The code is exact, excepting `echo` statements which are used to show the result which the code return